# How to add more meaningful error message to has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

My User model has many addresses like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :address_line_1, :city, :state, :zip, presence: true
end
```

The `Address` model also has an `address_type` column to signify either a `work` or `home` address.

When I tried to save both addresses with errors, I'm getting something that seems weird to me:

```
a = User.last
a.addresses # This user has both a home and work address
=>  #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy #<Address id: 1, address_line_1: "123 Bob St.", city: "Blah", zip: "12345", state: "KY", address_type: "home", user_id: "1">, #<Address id: 2, address_line_1: "123 Jane St.", city: "Bloh", zip: "12345", state: "KY", address_type: "work", user_id: "1">

a.assign_attributes(addresses_attributes: { "0" => { address_line_1: nil, id: 1 }, "1" => { address_line_1: nil, id: 2 } })
a.save # This is false
a.errors.details # Shows only 1 error
=> {:"addresses.address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}
```

As you can see from above, Rails only provided 1 error when both addresses are invalid have that same error. I can't tell from looking at that whether or not if both are invalid or just one, and I can't tell which one has the error. Is there a way to provide a more detailed error message, maybe something like these:

```
{:"work_address.address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank}], :"home_address.address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}
```

Or at least include the object id:

```
{:"addresses.address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank, :ids=>[1,2]}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to the nested validation errors by specifying that the association index the errors via:

```
has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy, index_errors: true
```

Given the index, you can then determine the `addres_type`.

A complete example of `index_errors: true` can be seen in this article here: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/07/errors-can-be-indexed-with-nested-attrbutes-in-rails-5.html

Comment: I never knew about this before! But, sadly even with indexing, I don't think I can still determine which address record it is. Let's say the city is blank for both addresses, the error message would `{:"addresses[0].address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank}], :"addresses[1].address_line_1"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}`, I still can't determine is addresses[0] is the home or the work address. Maybe I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 0):

How about custom validation with something like this?

```
validate :addresses_valid

def addresses_valid
  addresses.each.with_index(1) do |a, index|
    next if [a.address_line_1, a.city, a.state, a.zip].all?

    errors.add "address #{index}", "is invalid"
  end
end
```

Read more at [Rails Guide Validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)